# How to pass value from web service to route and then to database call in Express and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am creating a small project to become familiar with NodeJS, Express and the MEAN stack in general. I'm also very new to web development.

I want to add search functionality to my little site. I have a controller, web service and a javascript file that contains all my database calls (MongoDB).

My question is: How do you pass the search value entered by the user from the web service to the route and then to the db? I've looked everywhere and but I have been unable to find a concrete example. This is what I've got so for.

My controller calls my web service.

```
this.search = function(searchValue,callback) {
    console.log(searchValue);
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/contacts/search/:searchValue',
        params: {searchValue: searchValue},
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    }).success(function(resp){
        console.log("here");
        callback(resp);
    }).error(function(){
        callback(undefined);
    });
};
```

Next, my web service calls my route...

```
router.get('/search/:searchValue', function(req, res) {
    db.search(req.params.searchValue, function(err,data){
        if(!err) {
            res.json(data);
        }else{
            res.json({code:-1,err:err});
        }
    });
});
```

Then the database call...

```
database.prototype.search = function(id,callback){
    mongo.connect(dbUrl, function(err, db) {
        if(!err) {
            db.collection('friends',function(err,coll){
                coll.find({friend:"Jimmy"}).toArray(function(err, items) {
                    db.close();
                    callback(null,items);
                });
            });
        }else{
            db.close();
            console.log("hi");
            callback(err,null);
        }
    });
};
```

Things work fine when I hard code my search value right into my db call (ie. "Jimmy" above). However, I don't know how to pass the search value from my web service to my route and then to the db. I get errors like the route cannot be found or I cannot connect to the database. Silly things that go away when I hard code values.

Anyhow, thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your router (what you call your web service) you're calling your database search function like this:

```
router.get('/search/:searchValue', function(req, res) {
    db.search(req.params.searchValue, function(err,data){
        ...
```

Notice you're passing to your `db.search` `req.params.searchValue`

But in your database you have your same search function defined as:

```
database.prototype.search = function(id, callback){...
```

which as you can see, takes `id` as argument. 
There's clearly a disconnect here. You're passing it the `searchValue` from router but you've defined it to take `id`.

Then further down in database search function you doing this:

```
database.prototype.search = function(id,callback){
    mongo.connect(dbUrl, function(err, db) {
        if(!err) {
            db.collection('friends',function(err,coll){
                coll.find({friend:"Jimmy"}).toArray(function(err, items) {
                    ...
```

you're calling `coll.find` to which you should presumably want to pass that `searchValue`. There's another disconnect here, you're never using the `id` that you took as a parameter.

If you say that for things to work fine all you gotta do is put "Jimmy", which I guess is the `searchValue`, then you should try this:

```
database.prototype.search = function(searchValue,callback){ // replace id with searchValue
    mongo.connect(dbUrl, function(err, db) {
        if(!err) {
            db.collection('friends',function(err,coll){
                           // use searchValue here
                coll.find({friend:searchValue}).toArray(function(err, items) {
                    ...
```

---

**edit**

There's some problem on your client side code as well

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/contacts/search/:searchValue',
    params: {searchValue: searchValue},
    headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
```

Here you're making an AJAX call with Angular's $http module. And you're making a GET request but you're passing `params` along with it, which is usually only passed when you make a POST request. Also, the way you've defined your route you're only reading `searchValue` from the URL itself. So the URL here should be like this:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/contacts/search/' + searchValue,
    // params: { no need for params }
    ...
```

To explain a bit more how URL params work:

If you request a URL like this

```
GET /contacts/search/abcd
```

then you'd define your Express route handler like this

```
app.get('/contacts/search/:name', function(req, res, next){
    req.params.name //=> "abcd"
});
```

Notice the syntax of route definition `/contacts/search/:name` is only used for defining the route in Express.

The `/:name` part is just to assign a variable name - `name` to the value - `"abcd"` so it could be accessed as `req.params.name`

Which is why this is wrong

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/contacts/search/:searchValue',
```

it should be this

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/contacts/search/' + yourActualSearchValue,
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It's starting to respond a lot more normally now. Would you happen to know how to access my parameter from req? What I have up there isn't working. However, hard coding the value does work. Im not accessing the parameter from req correctly.

Comment: Could you elaborate more what you exactly mean by "access my parameter from req"? Is it not `req.params.searchValue`? Also, do you mean it's still not working after you made the changes? If that's the case could you update your original post with your latest code.

Comment: @user3286381 I didn't notice before but there was some problem with your client-side `$http` call as well. Please checkout the update and make the changes to your code

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much. Yea, i'm totally new to web development and so your explanation on params really helped. Thanks a lot dude. Much appreciated.